# Is it possible to add custom validation to validate sitecore rendering datasource?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I need to validate the referenced datasource item fields based on the rendering it is used in. Since the datasource items are used in multiple components I need a rendering based validation. Is it possible to achieve this in sitecore?

Comment: just to clarify - do you mean this 'Data Source' field?
http://prntscr.com/fu7fv9

Comment: @AlekseyShevchenko Yes I need to validate the fields of the referenced datasource item based on the rendering.

Comment: check my answer below please

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you mean "validate the referenced datasource item fields"? Do you want to validate if the fields meet a certain criteria, e.g. "length is less than 100 characters"? Or you want to validate that "certain fields are completed only when they are used by certain renderings"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed in case if you want to validate fields and do it exactly on rendering you have to use Sitecore Rendering Parameters. How to use that you can find [here](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/sitecore-rendering-parameters-part-1--how-and-why-to-use-rendering-parameters).
The main idea:

1. your data source template should be based on */system/layout/rendering parameters/Standard Rendering Parameters* one.
2. your rendering should contain a reference to the appropriate template within *Parameters Template* field (*Editor Options* section).
3. you have to setup necessary validations to fields of template (mentioned in 1st point). This [post](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/using-sitecore-field-validators/) will be helpful.

After that when you click on *Edit component properties* on your rendering:
[image]

You will see the additional section in *Control Properties* window (*Data* on the screen below). It comes from template mentioned in 1st point:
[image]

As an example I setup *Required* validation rule to *Text* field to show that it works.

Comment: I understand the rendering parameters validation, But what I require is a validation applied for rendering itself so that I can get the datasource item and validate the fields in it based on the rendering it is used in.

Comment: @Bevin if so I think you need to setup validation on '/sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Rendering Parameters/Standard Rendering Parameters/General/Data Source' field.

Comment: I'll take a look into it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @aleksey-shevchenko, This solution is working for me but I realized my approach was really dumb for the problem. As a workaround I inherited and created on different data templates inherited from a common base template and used suppress validation functionality of sitecore to get different field validation for different derived templates.

Comment: @Bevin if it is not difficult for you could you please mark my answer as right

Comment: Sorry, I thought I did that.